# Dockerfile commands are applied when building the image and not when running the container

Tags: docker

That's a very basic `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
```

The following is from [Docker documents](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

***The COPY instruction copies new files or directories from `src` and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path `dest`***

When we build an image from the above Dockerfile, there is no container yet and no filesystem I guess. However, we can see that `npm install` is applied while building the image. I would expect all this stuff to be applied when running the container and not when building the image since the latter is just a blueprint. What did I get wrong?

Comment: The statement in the question title is correct: the Dockerfile is a list of instructions that happen during `docker build`, which happens before you run a container from the built image.  (Technically the `RUN` commands happen inside temporary containers.)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Commands you specify in Dockerfile are run while building images. only entrypoint/command is run while starting up container. Following links should be useful for you
[#1](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/understanding-dockers-cmd-and-entrypoint-instructions).

and [#2](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-images-vs-containers)